# How to I make an element on a website that prints at a specific size?

Tags: image-processing, printing, screen-resolution, dimensions

I am using php and am generating a page of player id cards for a game tournament which can be printed out.

How do I set up an element (for example a div) so that it prints at the size of a credit card? (86 millimeters x 54 millimeters)

is there any way to make sure the size of the cards prints correctly on different computers or will the resolution settings of their screen affect the print size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether displaying text or images for the cards, simply set a size for height and width in pixels. If you are using text, nominate the width of the outer border or div area in pixels. If using an images then their size parameters should already be set.

Then to ensure that the printer does not alter anything, drop the card content into a table or div that is set to width and height in pixels to match the commonly used printable area of an A4 page. Pick a size that will fill an A4 without cropping.

For example:

```
<table align="center" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="600" height="900" >
<tr> 
<td align="center"><img src="image.jpg" width="500" height="500"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

There is a popular belief that this will be affected by the resolution of the computer screen and the image, but this method has been tested and proven to work.